# In Flutter, how can I create a shape like this XML shape I created in android java app

Tags: flutter, dart, shapes, flutter-textinputfield

I created an android app in java and I had this xml shape in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="20dp"/>
<padding android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:bottom="10dp"/>
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/DodgerBlue"/>
<solid android:color="@color/White" />
```

[image]

Now I am creating a flutter app, so I am trying to create the same shape in flutter, but I had no luck.

Can someone guide me on how to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to add border radius and border width is a container using BoxDecoration

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            _simpleBorder(),
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
  }

  Widget _simpleBorder() => Container(
        width: 200,
        height: 50,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)),
      );
}
```

[image: border]

There are more advanced ways using shapes in Flutter. If this does not solve your question I can provide more info on shapes

Answer (score 2):

There are widget like `TextFiled`,`TextFormFiled` can be used to take user input.

Lets split the xml code

- `android:radius="20dp"` it should have 20px(flutter use pixel) for border and TextFormFiled widget can provide different borders based on state.
- `padding android:left="10dp...."` having 10px padding
- `stroke android:width="1dp"` means border thickness
- and background color

We can use `OutlineInputBorder`

```dart
const border = OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 68, 255),
        width: 1,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(20),
      ),
    );
```

The the widget will be

```dart
class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const border = OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 68, 255),
        width: 1,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(20),
      ),
    );
    return TextFormField(
      enabled: false,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Colors.grey.shade50,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        border: border,
        enabledBorder: border,
        focusedBorder: border,
        errorBorder: border,
        disabledBorder: border,
        focusedErrorBorder: border,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For more, head on [flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html)

Comment: oh, forgot about background, use `filled:true` and `fillColor: Colors.white,` on `InputDecoration`, actuall color is `grey.shade50` you need to remove const on that case, or use hexColor